# System variable - Procedure name within procedure

Tags: mysql

When writing a stored procedure in MySQL is there a system variable that has the stored procedure's name?

I want to do some logging in stored procedures and I want to use the procedure name as a process id without hard coding the name in every proc.  Something like `me.name equals myStoredProc`

Comment: The short answer is "No". Can you share your architecture decision? Seems you are trying to make simple things complicated